# PHP Get Date and Time when a button is clicked and store it in a variable

Tags: php

I would love to know if this is possible using PHP. For an instance, I want the current date and time be stored on a variable once I click the submit button. Here is what I have in mind:

```
<?php
if ($_POST["submit"] == 'submit')
//store the variable here
?>

<form action ="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

I am quite new to PHP, hope you guys can help me! cheers.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Why don't you just get today's date using date('Y-m-d H:i:s')?

Comment: Leaving some enlightenment comment after casting downvote would also be helpful as well, cheers!

Comment: @MarkTe check out my answer, might work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be sufficient for your needs, give it a shot. You can change up the format of `date()` by passing different parameters to it (like switch up month and day and so on). Check up on that [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). Also, don't forget to [set your timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

```
<h2>Click</h2>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <button name="click" class="click">Click me!</button>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['click']))
{
    $date_clicked = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');;
    echo "Time the button was clicked: " . $date_clicked . "<br>";
}
?>
```

The date is stored in the variable `$date_clicked` if you didn't notice. You can do whatever you want with that afterwards, like store it in your MySQL database.

Comment: It worked! Thanks jvitasek, now all I need is to change the format, thanks for the link as well. Cheers!

Comment: @MarkTe Great to see you're learning, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["submit"])){

 // getting current Date Time OOP way
 $currentDateTime = new \DateTime();

 //set timeZone
 $currentDateTime->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
 $dateTime = $currentDateTime->format('l-j-M-Y H:i:s A');

}

?>

<form action ="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```